# How to get Intersection and Complement at the same time?

Tags: list-manipulation

In the following example, a is a list of integers, and b is a list of integer triplets.  If any triple has two elements in a, I want the 3rd element Sow'd into c.  This code works, but every time if finds an intersection of 2 elements, it has to search that long list a again to get the compliment.  Is there a way to be more efficient?

```
a = RandomInteger[10000, 10000];
b = RandomInteger[1000, {300, 3}];
c = Reap[Do[
   If[Length[Intersection[a, b[[i]]]] == 2, 
    Sow[Complement[b[[i]], a]]], {i, 1, Length[b]}]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why use `Intersection` at all?

```
Map[Complement[#, a]&, b] // Cases[{_}]
```

Comment: Why didn't I think of this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Better?

```
a = RandomInteger[30000, 30000];
b = RandomInteger[1000, {300, 3}];
c = Reap[
     Do[
      If[
       Length[Intersection[a, b[[i]]]] == 2,
       Sow[Complement[b[[i]], a]]
       ],
      {i, 1, Length[b]}]
     ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First

nf = Nearest[DeleteDuplicates[a]];
d = Association@Reap[
      Do[
       intersection = Union @@ nf[x, {1, 0}];
       If[Length[intersection] == 2,
        Sow[intersection, "Intersections"];
        Sow[Complement[x, intersection], "Complements"];
        ],
       {x, b}],
      _, Rule][[2]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
c[[2, 1]] == d["Complements"]
```

> 1.05426
>
> 0.011678
>
> True

The intersections can be obtained by `d["Intersections"]`.

Comment: To state the underlying principle, if the `a` list is going to remain the same for many such queries, it is typically more efficient to use a method that preprocesses the long list. An alternative to making a `NearestFunction`, not quite as fast, is to use `Dispatch`: `removals = Dispatch[Thread[a -> Nothing]];
c2 = Select[b /. removals, Length[#] == 1 &]`